# Angular.js – Where to extend JavaScript Date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I want to extend the basic Date object of JavaScript with more functionality like the following:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var date = new Date(this.getTime());
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Thursday in current week decides the year.
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    // January 4 is always in week 1.
    var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
    return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
};
```

Currently, I put this logic into a file called `objectExtenders.js` which is linked in `index.html` like this:

```
<script src="scripts/misc/dateExtenders.js"></script>
```

It doesn't really seem appropriate to put this logic into a service or so, since it modifies the global Date object. Therefore I guess there's no point in injecting such a service into specific controllers, since it will apply to all controllers anyway.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead create a service called `DateUtils` or so that you inject into your controllers, and that service could have functions that work on dates.

So instead of doing `myDate.getWeek()` you will call `DateUtils.getWeek(myDate)`.

Comment: That's also what I was thinking about. The only downside I see, is that a code like `date.getWeek()` is little bit more semantic. Or is it generally better to not modify the global Date object and use the approach of an injectable service?

Comment: It's better not to modify anything in the global scope.

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/  I would think given the considerations in extending native objects, it's safer to use a service as suggested above.

Comment: @amann at least many devs prefer not to extend the standard objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this kind of modification is global. It affects all `Date` objects whether they are within angular territory or not. So this question is not in any way related to angular or any other framework. Simply put the code in a JavaScript file and include that file where you want to add this functionality.